# Why is the device parameter of torch.cuda.device probably greater than torch.cuda.device_count()?

Tags: pytorch

It's the code:

```
torch.cuda.device_count()
# output: 1
d2 = torch.cuda.device(2)
# d2.idx = 2
```

Is it for the model running on other device?

Answer (score 0):

`torch.cuda.device_count()` returns the number of GPUs available, whereas `torch.cuda.device(device)` is a `context-manager`. It facilitates the proper handling of resources, i.e., automatic setup and release of resources after usage. So, the argument you are passing in this function doesn't mean you are switching/setting to that device. In order to set current device, you should use `torch.cuda.set_device(device)`. Although, as per the official documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html),

> Usage of this function is discouraged in favor of device. In most
>   cases it’s better to use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environmental variable.

To know more about torch.cuda.device() and how it works, go through [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1608) official pytorch discussion.